# SQL Server 11 can't exit single user mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

One of my databases is in single user mode, and i can't seem to switch it to multi user.

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDB
SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

When I run the above query, i get the following result

```
Changes to the state or options of database 'MyDB' cannot be made at this time. The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.
```

I've tried to query SQL Server from the master database to find all active connections to MyDB (`exec sp_who`), but when i do so i get the following error

```
Database 'MyDB' is already open and can only have one user at a time.
```

What am i supposed to do to exit single user mode?

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
exec sp_dboption 'db_name_here', 'single user', 'FALSE'
```

Comment: sp_dboption is deprecated (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187310(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Sorry.. I've missed that SQL Server 11 :/